# Migrate to Ng Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I'm using angular 8, with bootstrap     "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",

I want to migrate my application to ng-bootstrap, to avoid jquery

Any idea please

Answer (score -1):

Here is my approach -

- Map your current components with OOB `ng-bootstrap` component. Those are directly available use as it is.
- Refactor your component to replace older tags and directives with `ng-bootstrap` directives.
- Some of the component you will have to write completely from scratch.